# Replacing the same class in two different areas - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario:

```
<ul id = "content">

<li id = "ContentList">
<img src = "test.png" class = "icon" />
</ li
<li id = "ContentList">
<img src = "test.png" class = "icon" />
</ li

</ ul>
```

The images of the first and second (LI) are equal, but I need to insert two different images.

I can change all this using css:

```
.icon {
display: block;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url (newbanner.png) no-repeat;
width: 180px;
height: 236px;
padding-left: 180px;
}
```

How can I change the image of the first and second (LI) to something like:

```
.icon {
display: block;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url (newbanner1.png) no-repeat;
width: 180px;
height: 236px;
padding-left: 180px;
}

.icon {
display: block;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: url (newbanner2.png) no-repeat;
width: 180px;
height: 236px;
padding-left: 180px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have two ID's the same...that's invalid and not recommended. IDs should be unique on each page.

Comment: Presuming you mean with CSS, you can't. CSS is not a programming language.

Comment: Also, you seem to be adding a background image to another inline image. I'm not really sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Your HTML is broken, please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` selector that allows you to select one or more elements based on their order.

HTML:

```
<ul id="content">

<li>
<img src = "test.png" class = "icon" />
</ li
<li>
<img src = "test.png" class = "icon" />
</ li

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li:nth-child(1) .icon 
{
        display: block;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url (newbanner1.png) no-repeat;
        width: 180px;
        height: 236px;
        padding-left: 180px;
}

li:nth-child(2) .icon {
        display: block;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url (newbanner2.png) no-repeat;
        width: 180px;
        height: 236px;
        padding-left: 180px;
 }
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to hard-wire specifics about element order into CSS rules like this.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how you are going to use background image in `img` but as far as I know its not worth doing like this, instead you can assign background image for `<li>` and inside that you can use `img` tag. whatever the code you showed us I tried to show you one of the way you can try.

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrqjup2j/)**

```
.i1, .i2 {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 180px;
    height: 236px;
    padding-left: 180px;
}
.i1 {
    background: #ccc url(newbanner1.png) no-repeat;
}
.i2 {
    background: red url(newbanner2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="content">
    <li>
        <img src="test.png" class="i1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="test.png" class="i1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="test.png" class="i2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="test.png" class="i2" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Update: Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrqjup2j/4/)**

```
.i1, .i2 {
    display:block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 236px;
    margin:5px auto;
}
.i1 img, .i2 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="content">
    <li class="i1">
        <img src="http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9835079_orig.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="i1">
        <img src="http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9835079_orig.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="i2">
        <img src="http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9835079_orig.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="i2">
        <img src="http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9835079_orig.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```